# Rails - Routing Error - Calling a model from another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, controller

**Question: My goal is to list projects under the user's page, and have comment box render under each project that is listed on this user page. But when I do try to render the comment box form, I get a routing error. I know this is because it is not being able to pull out the ID of the project. My guess is something to do with the controller but have not figured out. Does somebody know how I can solve this?**

```
Routing Error
No route matches {:controller=>"comments", :format=>nil, :project_id=>#<Project id: nil...>}
```

For my application, I have created models and controllers for Users, Projects, and Comments. Comments belong to Projects and Projects belong to Users

**user.rb**

```
has_many :projects
```

**project.rb**

```
has_many :comments
belongs_to :user
```

**comment.rb**

```
belongs_to :project
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :users do
  resources :projects do
    resources :comments
  end
end

resources :projects do
  resources :comments 
end

resources: comments
```

**view/users/projects.html.erb**

```
<%= render @projects %>
```

**view/projects/_project.html.erb**

```
<%= project.content %>
<%= render 'comments/form' %>
```

**view/comments/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for([@project, @project.comments.build]) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, :class => "span12", :rows => "3" %>
    </div>

    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>

    <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Add Comment", :class => "btn btn-header" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**comments_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @comment = @project.comments.create!(params[:comment])

  if @comment.save
    redirect_to projects_user_path(@project.user)
  end   
end
```

Error from the redirect above

```
NoMethodError in CommentsController#create
undefined method `user'
```

Comment: There is an error in your association. Is `belongs_to :user` and `belongs_to project` in singular.

Comment: thanks. fixed. routing error still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**view/projects/_project.html.erb**

```
<%= project.content %>
<%= render 'comments/form', project: project %>
```

**view/comments/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for([project, project.comments.build]) do |f| %>
...
```

You have to pass the project to form partial.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, so it posts now to my database, but when I try to fix up the redirect_to in the comments controller to @comment.project, I get a NoMethodError. Since comment belongs_to project, why can't I be able to make this redirect_to?

Comment: I edited question above to show : "redirect_to projects_user_path(@project.user)"

Comment: Added to bottom of my question above.

Comment: Look like the error is in `User.find(params[:user_id])`. Check the params in server log.

Comment: That's because `params[:project_id]` is nil, the `@project` is nil and `user` is not a method of nil class.

Comment: Okay. Been playing around for awhile, do you have any suggestions on how to fix? Thanks

Comment: Try `<%= f.hidden_field :projet_id, :value => project.id %>`